# Dropdown navigation menu bar is working in IE7 but not in FireFox

Tags: html, css

I have a dropdown bar -

```
    <div class="buttonContainer">
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a class="menu1one" href="">Dashboard</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <div class="noLink">Tasks</div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">View</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Edit</a></li>
                    <!--[if lte IE 6]></a><![endif]--> 
                </ul>
                <!--[if lte IE 6]></a><![endif]--> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="noLink">Dictionaries</div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">Needs</a></li>
                    <li><a href="">Activities</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!--[if lte IE 6]></a><![endif]--> 
            </li>
            <li>
                <div class="noLink">Admin</div>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="">User Accounts</a></li>
                </ul>
                <!--[if lte IE 6]></a><![endif]--> 
            </li>   
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS -

```
/*dropdown menu*/
.menu { float:left; width:100%; font-family: arial; border-top:1px solid #4c597f; background-color: #1079b5; min-width:950px; }
.menu .buttonContainer { padding:0 0 0 200px; }
.menu ul { padding:0; margin:0; list-style-type:none; }
.menu ul li { margin:0; float:left; position:relative; background-color:#153d71; }
.menu ul li a, .menu ul li a:visited { float:left; display:block; text-decoration:none; color:#ddf; padding:0px 16px; line-height:25px; height:30px; }
.menu ul li a:hover { background-color:#9fc1ed; color: #153d71;}
.noLink { display:block; color:#ddf; padding:0px 16px; line-height:25px; height:30px; }
.menu ul li:hover { width:auto; }
.menu ul li ul { display: none; }
/* specific to non IE browsers */
.menu ul li:hover ul { display:block; position:absolute; top:30px; left:0; width:154px; border-bottom:1px solid #000; }
.menu ul li:hover ul.endstop { left:-92px; }
.menu ul li:hover ul li ul { display: none; }
.menu ul li:hover ul li a { display:block; background:#1079b5; color:#000; height:auto; line-height:15px; padding:4px 16px; width:120px; border:1px solid #000; border-bottom:0; }
.menu ul li:hover ul li a.drop { background:#ccd no-repeat 3px 8px; }
.menu ul li:hover ul li a:hover { background-color: #153d71; color: #FFFFFF; }
.menu ul li:hover ul li a:hover.drop { background: #ccd no-repeat 3px 8px; }
.menu ul li:hover ul li:hover ul { display:block; position:absolute; left:153px; top:-1px; }
.menu ul li:hover ul li:hover ul.left { left:-153px; }
/* IE6 */
.menu ul li a:hover ul { display:block; position:absolute; top:30px; t\op:33px; background:#153d71; left:0; border-bottom:1px solid #000; }
.menu ul li a:hover ul.endstop { left: -92px; }
.menu ul li a:hover ul li a { display:block; background:#153d71; color:#000; height:1px; line-height:15px; padding:4px 16px; width:154px; w\idth:120px; border:1px solid #000; border-bottom:0; }
.menu ul li a:hover ul li a.drop { background:#ccd url('') no-repeat 3px 8px; padding-bottom:4px; }
.menu ul li a:hover ul li a ul { visibility:hidden; position:absolute; height:0; width:0; }
.menu ul li a:hover ul li a:hover { color:#000; background: #ccd url('') no-repeat 3px 8px; }
.menu ul li a:hover ul li a:hover.drop { background: #ccd url('') no-repeat 3px 8px; }
.menu ul li a:hover ul li a:hover ul { visibility:visible; position:absolute; top:0; color:#000; left:153px; }
.menu ul li a:hover ul li a:hover ul.left { left:-153px; }
```

The dropdown menu is working well or showing up on hover in IE7 but not responding in Firefox.

Could anybody help me with this please?? I tried position : relative for inner li a:hover and it shows the menu but extends the whole div till its end. What is to be changed here?

Also, i don't want to use javascript/jquery for this.

-thanks

EDITED - I have found the solution to get it to work. I added 'position: absolute;' attribute to the .menu{} in the css. That made it work... Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution to get it to work. I added 'position: absolute;' attribute to the .menu{} in the css. That made it work... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I just tested on IE7 its working fine to me
http://jsfiddle.net/vcN5g/

Comment: yes. thats right, it is working in IE7. not working in Firefox as i've mentioned in my original post. Thanks.

Comment: It is working on fire fox as well. what version of ff r u using?

Comment: version - 10.0.2. It actually works in jsfiddle but doesn't work in my project :( . Anyways, I added 'position: absolute;' attribute to the .menu{} in the css. It works now. Thanks very much for ur time.